# I'm trying to display the numbers 0-99 by multiplexing to two 7 segment displays. One number does not display

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, hardware, 7-segment

```
//Numbers 0-9.
int numberArray[10][7] = {
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }, //0
  { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //1
  { 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 }, //2
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0 }, //3
  { 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0 }, //4
  { 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //5
  { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //6
  { 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, //7
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, //8
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 }, //9
};

//Turn off all segments (common anode --> high = off)
void reset() {
  for (int i = 12; i >= 6; i--) {
    digitalWrite(i, 1);
  }
}

//turn on both segments (don't write anything to them)
void on(){
  digitalWrite(4,1);
  digitalWrite(5,1);
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  reset();
  on();
}
void loop() {
  for (int i=0;i<99;i++){
    twoDigitNumber(i);
  }
}

void twoDigitNumber(int number){
    digitalWrite(4,1);                   //turn on left display
    digitalWrite(5,0);                   //turn on right display
    digit(int(floor(number/10)));        //display the tens digit
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(4,0);                   //turn off left display
    digitalWrite(5,1);                   //turn on right display
    digit(int(number-floor(number/10))); //display the ones digit
    delay(10);
}

//make the displays show a single digit number
void digit(int number) {
  for (int i = 12; i >= 6; i--) {
    digitalWrite(i, numberArray[number][12 - i]);
  }
}
```

This is my first time doing anything at all with Arduino, and I'm also brand new to the language.

I have a bit of circuitry attached to the display. I'm using 2n5551 NPN transistors to act as a switch. Collectors connected to 5v, bases are connected to pin 4/5 with a 200 ohm resistor. Emitters are connected to the common anode of the displays. pin 4 is for the left display, pin 5 for the right display. These are to display different numbers in each display. Something's probably wrong with this but I'm having a hard time learning about transistors.

When I use the function twoDigitNumber(), it only displays the number on the left display, but I can see a very dim copy of that same number on the right display. int() is there because i thought floor() would make it into a double and cause issues, but that didn't fix it.

I know every segment works. When I use digit(), it shows the same digit on both displays (as expected).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This line looks wrong: `digit(int(number-floor(number/10)));` - don't you want the number mod 10? That is: `digit (number % 10);`

Comment: If the number is 42 your calculation would give you `42 - 4` which would be 38 and that is not in the range 0 to 9.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to multiply the tens by 10 first before subtracting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing `pinmode(4,OUTPUT)` in your `setup` routine.

As a general comment, using variable names instead of 'magic numbers' makes your code easier to read - and thus usually easier to debug. for example:

```
const int leftDisplay = 4;
const int rightDisplay = 5;
const int seg1 = 12;
const int seg2 = 11;
[...]
```

You can also use `HIGH` and `LOW` instead of `1` and `0` for the `digitalwrite` elements

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I'm ashamed the solution was so easy.